# WebsitePanel portal crashes

Tags: websitepanel

[image]Every time i log in to the WebsitePanel and try to navigate to any section including the file manager section, the portal logs me out automatically saying session id is corrupted or not valid.

I have tried resetting browser, generating the certificate, including chrome flags, but the issue still remains.

Answer (score 0):

It will work on a different computer.

Comment: tried that didn't work. I'm assuming i gotta find the support people to have the issue resolved